# How to use medium-zoom library together with lazysizes?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, web-deployment, user-experience, image-loading

[lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) allows improving UX with transformations on image loading and [medium-zoom](https://github.com/francoischalifour/medium-zoom) unlocks zooming images like Medium. The problem is that lazysizes performs the transformations asynchronously.
So if you register images for zooming somewhere in the page footer by running something like

```
mediumZoom( "[data-zoomable]" )
```

it would most likely be executed before the transformations done. And zooming won't work, because it would bind to detached nodes. So how we can use the libraries together?

Answer (score 0):

lazysizes exposes an event API (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#js-api---events). So we can register image nodes for zooming when it's already safe:

```
document.addEventListener( "lazybeforeunveil", e => {
   mediumZoom( "[data-zoomable]" );
});
```